# Добавление файлов из вложенных папок по шаблону

Tags: git

Есть некий проект с древовидной структурой папок, обслуживаемый git'ом. Я нахожусь в консоли на верхнем уровне проекта и у меня есть несколько файлов, которые были изменены, во вложенных папках. Я вижу эти измененные файлы по команде `git status`, например:

> [image: Изменённые файлы]

Подобных файлов может быть много и я хочу их добавить с помощью шаблонных имён. Например, добавить все `csv` файлы командой `git add *.csv`, а все `txt` файлы командой `git add *.txt`. Я выполняю эти две команды, однако в результате вижу, что в индекс добавились только файлы `*.csv`:

> [image: Только один добавлен]

Почему не добавились файлы с расширением `txt`?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо за советы, Александр. Не забывайте начинать предложения с заглавной буквы :)

Comment: спасибо за советы! не забывайте про удобство читателей, пожалуйста.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin удобство не страдает. Вся нужная информация есть уже и в тексте. Картинки приведены для демонстрации различий между добавленными и недобавленными файлами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема может быть в том, что в папках, уровень которых выше папки проблемного файла (например, в корне, или в `/one/`), существуют файлы, удовлетворяющие шаблону, т.е. в данном случае, файлы с расширением `txt`. Таким образом, `git add *.txt` находит этот файл из корня или другого уровня, выше желаемого (однако он не изменён и не отражается в результатах команды `git status`) и прекращает искать файлы в папках с большей вложенностью.

Таким образом, чтобы гарантированно добавить файлы из вложенных папок, придётся указать полный путь к этим папкам. Но в некоторых случаях может быть полезна комбинация вида `*/*.txt`, которая найдёт файлы во вложенных папках (ограничится тем уровнем вложенности, где будут найдены первые файлы, удовлетворяющие шаблону).

В данном случае, после команды `git add */*.txt` проблемный файл будет добавлен:

> [image: Файл добавлен]